# find the volume of a region bounded by $y=\sqrt{x} ,x=0, y=2$ around the Y-axis.

Tags: calculus

$y=\sqrt{x} ,x=0, y=2$ around the Y-axis.

I can't seem to get the setup right. I know the formula for cylindrical shell is $2\pi rht $
my problem is that I'm not getting the right answer ($8\pi$) 
I thought the setup would be

$2\pi \int x*\sqrt{x}dx $

but I keep getting it wrong. I think the upper bound is 4 and the lower bound is 0 (since square root 4 is 2 which is where y is) I'm not even sure that I should be taking x for the radius since x=0. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The formula you use there is for volumes of graphs revolving *around the* $\;y$-axis...

Comment: Perhaps he actually wants the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluating your integral:

$$2 \pi \int_0^4 x\sqrt{x} dx = 2 \pi \int_0^4 x^{3/2} dx = 2\pi \frac{2}{5}x^{5/2}\bigg|_0^4 = \frac{128\pi}{5}$$

Hopefully this is what you were getting.

BUT. If we rotate around the $x$-axis (not the $y$-axis) then we will get $8\pi$ as follows:

$$2\pi\int_0^2 y\cdot y^2 dy = 2\pi\int_0^2 y^3 dy = 2 \pi \frac{y^4}{4}\bigg|_0^2 = 8\pi$$

So the question now remains as to which axis you really want.

Comment: that first answer is what I was getting for the y-axis. Unfortunately the paper does say y-axis. I'll have to ask again tomorrow.

Comment: It was the x-axis for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want the area between $\;y=\sqrt x\;,\;\;y=2\;$ and $\;x=0\;$ revolved around the $\;x$-axis, thus you get

$$\pi\int\limits_0^4\left(2^2-(\sqrt x)^2\right)dx=\pi\left(16-\frac124^2\right)=8\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

If revolving around the $x$-axis makes more sense to you, then we can consider revolving the inverse function of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ around the $x$-axis with the appropriate bounds.

Of course, $f^{-1}(x) = x^2$, and so revolving $y = x^2$ around the $x$-axis from $x = 0$ to $x = 2$ will yield the same result.