# Is their a special way to factor when doing integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

(Very sorry this could probably be cleared up if I had rights to comment, however I am new here)
Anyways, I was going on stack overflow looking for help on a problem I keep getting wrong. For the record my class just went over these, it is very possible there are tricks we will learn in the future.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819828/find-the-volume-of-a-region-bounded-by-y-sqrtx-x-0-y-2-around-the-y-axis?newreg=164b60cddd104ca5b2fa9f5ef158e2b5) thread covered the exact problem, except the user edited it later so it was revolving around the y axis not x axis.  I need it revolved around the x axis.

Unfortunately almost none of the answers made sense, I couldn't follow there math at all.

One of the replies that I could understand was this.

> You want the area between $\;y=\sqrt x\;,\;\;y=2\;$ and $\;x=0\;$
>   revolved around the $\;x$-axis, thus you get
>
> $$\pi\int\limits_0^4\left(2^2-(\sqrt(x)^2\right)dx=\pi\left(16-\frac124^2\right)=8\pi$$

This answer got it right, and seemed to make sense.  However I can not follow its math... at all.  It would seem to me like there is a shortcut of some sort when squaring a factor that has an x in it. Is their?

Just for fun and so I can try out the math scripting thin here is how I would tackle it.
$$\pi\int\limits_0^4\left(2-\sqrt(x)\right)\left(2-\sqrt(x)\right)dx$$
$$\pi\int\limits_0^4\left(4-(2x)^2 + (1/4)x^2\right)dx$$
$$\pi\left[4x -\frac{((8x^\frac{2}{3}))}{2} + x\right]_0^4$$
$$=\pi\frac{8}{3}$$
If anyone sees my stupid mistake please let me know!

(Note: Apparently my math script is still a work in progress, I couldn't find a good tutorial, or how to properly show devision... sorry)

Comment: To create a fraction $\frac{a}{b}$, use the command `\frac{a}{b}`.

Comment: One thing: you expand $a^2-b^2$ as $(a-b)(a-b)$ while it should be $(a-b)(a+b)$. Easier, though, would be just to simplify $(\sqrt{x})^2$ to $x$ and evaluate the integral of $4-x$.